# itext xmlworker doesn't work with custom font family

Tags: java, itext

My application parses html and put the content in pdf, now it needs to support multiple fonts ex: Myanmar and Chinese.

I am able to do this with phrases but not with html even for single font family

**Working Code**

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/home/a2.pdf"));
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("KozMinPro-Regular", "UniJIS-UCS2-H", false);
Font font1 = FontFactory.getFont("/home/mm3.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, false);
FontSelector fs = new FontSelector();
fs.addFont(font);
fs.addFont(font1);
Phrase phrase = fs.process("長");
phrase.add(fs.process("၀န္ထမ္းလစလႊာ( လ )"));
phrase.add(fs.process("123aab"));
document.open();
document.add(phrase);
document.close();
```

Tried with XMLWorker but it didn't work:

```
final MyFontFactory fontFactory = new MyFontFactory();
FontFactory.register("/home/Downloads/mm3.ttf");
FontFactory.setFontImp(fontFactory);

final HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(fontFactory));
final CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);
Document document = new Document();

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/home/a2.pdf"));
document.open();
String str="<span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Deduc၀န္ထမ္းလစာေပးေခ်လႊာ( လစာငွေ )tions哈罗</span> ";
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
// step 5
document.close();
```